# Puedo imprimir el objeto completo pero no un elemento del objeto js

Tags: angularjs

estoy trabajando en Angular.
Mediante un Factory le envio un objeto al Controller y quiero trabajar con dicho objeto pero no puedo acceder a los elementos del objeto, pero si hago un console.log() del objeto, entonces me muetra todos los datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengan en cuenta que SRConsulta es el Factory, en la imagen de abajo me imprime todo el objeto correctamente pero al querer acceder al valor: "edificio", este sale como *undefined*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo del Factory:

```
.factory('SRConsulta', function(SalasReunionesInstancia, SalasReunionesAreas, SalasReunionesEdificios, SalasReunionesPisos, Contactos, $rootScope, UserPermission) {
var r = {};
r.permisos = {};
var usuario = UserPermission.findByName({username: $rootScope.username}, function(usuario) {
    if(usuario.edificio) {
        r.permisos.edificio = usuario.edificio;
    }

    if(usuario.piso) {
        r.permisos.piso = usuario.piso;
    }
});

return r;
```

});

Alguien sabe? Gracias

Comment: Angular o AngularJS? En cualquier caso, deberías añadir el código donde no te funciona para que veamos el escenario, no capturas de pantalla

Comment: Asegúrate de que el objeto sea construido sincronizadamente. Puede que la factoría esté devolviendo el objeto asincronamente. Si es asíncrono, asegúrate de que al momento de hacer el console.log, sí esté la información.

Comment: Listo, ahi ya agregue el codigo del Factory, en el controller solo hago el console.log(), nada mas, no hay mas codigo que el console.log().

Gracias

Comment: `findByName` realiza una peticion ajax?

Comment: No, findByName es un metodo del modelo UserPermission.
Claro, hace la consulta a Mongo, no se si sera Ajax, pero te trae los datos correctamente

Comment: la construcción del objeto depende de una función aparte... debes asegurarte de que el hilo de ejecución sea síncrono.

Comment: En que parte de la ejecución de tu codigo estas imprimiendo el objeto?? Estas haciendo un `console.log` o estas poniendo un breakpoint e imprimiendo en la consola del devtools simplemente escribiendo la variable en la consola?